# Android:can not save arrayList<String> in my firebase-realtime

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin, firebase-storage

[image: my result in firebase-realtime]

I try to add accident in firebase-realtime  with some information and some images, only the information are saved, the images paths are saved in firebase-storage but not in firebase-realtime.when I get the path of images from firebase-storage. I put this result path in arrayList of String. I want to put this arrayList in accident .I don't know why  only the information are saved and the arrayList not saved, can some one help me please ?

```
class Accident (
        var date:String?,
        var id:String?,
        var description:String?,

//        var video:Array<String>?=null,
//        var gravite:Int?=null,
        val geolocalisation:Localisation?,
        var photos: ArrayList<String>?,
        val adress:String?
        //var nbVictime:Int?=null
): Serializable

class Localisation( var altitude:Double=0.0,
                    var longitude:Double = 0.0)
    : Serializable {
}



fun loadDatabase(firebaseData: DatabaseReference) {
        uploadFile()
        var loc = Localisation(currentLatLng!!.latitude, currentLatLng!!.longitude)
        var uri=tabpath as ArrayList<String>
val availableAccident: List<Accident> = mutableListOf(

                Accident(SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd_HH:mm:ss").format(Date()), "", "il est tres grave", loc, uri, "Monastir")

        )
            var t=""
        availableAccident.forEach {

            val key = firebaseData.child("accidents").push().key

            it.id = key!!
            it.photos=uri

            if (key != null) {
                firebaseData.child("accidents").child(key).setValue(it)
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: this is my result on mode debug]

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: why the images are not added with attribute of accident in firebase-realtime ?